# Error while Entering API key in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, maas

Hi I have newly installed MAAS on ubuntu 12.04 while creating profile for web console of MAAS i get error message as "mass-cli: Command not found" which should be working as  described in below link

http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/maascli.html#api-key

Comment: I assume you have done the `sudo maas createsuperuser` step? Are you able to login to the web interface yet? It sounds like you are getting the error when running a command on the console, is that correct? Can you show an example of the command you ran to get the error?

Comment: could you give us complete log of what you have been doing ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running maas-cli on a machine other than the MaaS server itself, you will have to install the `maas-cli` package. Simply run

```
sudo apt-get install maas-cli
```

and then it should work.